# Heatmap plugin with relatively small area

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I'm trying to make a heatmap using points in a relatively small area (about 50km by 50km) and I just get a single red block every time (even after switching the color map to 'pseudocolor'). I've read several tutorials on how to make heat maps and it works when I use a larger area. Is there a limitation of the plugin so that it doesn't work with small areas, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the CRS of your point layer?

Comment: My CRS is NAD83/UTM 12

Comment: And the heatmap settings used are? Do you use QGIS 1.8 or the developer version?

Comment: I'm using 1.8. I can get a decent heat map with radii of one and higher (map units) and my decay ratio set at 1. When I use a radius smaller than one is where I get my problem. I read somewhere that the 'meter' option for radius doesn't work with 1.8 which I've confirmed.

Comment: Also, I'm exporting as a GeoTIFF and not messing with the advanced settings.